# Not getting data in latest firestore flutter library

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

While implementing the latest firestore library for flutter project, I am getting the the below error

> Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

CODE IMPLEMENTED

```
 return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){

      
      String itemTitle = snapshot.data.docs[index]['postContent'];

   return ContentList(postContent: postContent);

    });
```

Please guide me how to resolve, I am using Firestore ^0.14.3 dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on this line `String itemTitle = snapshot.data.docs[index]['postContent'];` where Flutter tries to look for an item in the map with the key of `'postContent'` but it is not found.

It is up to you to figure out why this so but I would also like refrain against asking questions which have already been asked. Next time just a tip, paste the error into Google and review the top links. :)

Below is a duplicate:

- https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3826

Comment: But the field does exist in the firestore database, please guide the solution, i referred your link but could not go to the right point, from next time I will search error first

Comment: Well that is the problem then, you calling for data which is not there within your code.

Comment: data is there for sure, with previous versions of the flutter firestore everything was working

Comment: Strange, try downgrading to a version when it was working, if that doesn't work its definitely an problem with you code. It might be a typo, or mistake somewhere that you are missing

Comment: Let me see what I can do about it

Comment: Actually you were right initially, there was bug related to field which did not existed